# Can Ansible variables be used on the left side of the ":" sign?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible, openshift

I'm writing an ansible playbook that reads a CSV file and creates a Kubernetes secret:

```yaml
  # Read a CSV file and print the entire lists
  - name: Read users from CSV file and return a dictionary
    community.general.read_csv:
      path: "{{ file }}"
    register: secrets
    delegate_to: localhost
    no_log: True

  - name: CREATE SECRET
    kubernetes.core.k8s:
      state: present
      kubeconfig: "~/.kube/config"
      definition: 
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Secret
        type: Opaque             
        metadata:
          name: "{{ item.SECRET_NAME }}"
          namespace: "{{ item.NAMESPACE | lower }}"     
        data:
          "{{item.SECRET_KEY_REF}}": "{{ item.SECRET_KEY_VALUE | b64encode }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ secrets.list }}"
```

In the "data" field, I want to create an entry `key:value` both with values of the CSV:

`"{{item.SECRET_KEY_REF}}": "{{ item.SECRET_KEY_VALUE | b64encode }}"`

but in this way it does not work. Is there a way to do this?